# Customize Google Marker Clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am working on an android application with Google Maps stuff. I want some customization in Clusters. Here following are the points I want to implement but not sure if this is feasible with Google Clusters.

- Can we decrease the tolerance of the clustering so they only
  cluster if the icons are about to touch/overlap currently they
  cluster when still a gap between them.
- There looks to be an issue with the counts/positioning, if you see my
  series of attached screenshots you can see the one off to the right somehow
  changes to a 2 when it is far enough away from the other 3 on the
  left.
- Is it possible to centre the cluster between the icons? That way the
  position of the icons don't change as much which might mean a big
  distance in the map.

Please check screenshots here at this link: [Screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o5ft72m5okwaq2k/AACoWhirliNvHOPfYojMAWBna?dl=0)

TIA, Satish